# Masking sub domain with a new domain while preserving the paths

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, subdomain, shared-hosting

I own a domain since long, just masking the names:

```
http://mydomain.com
```

Later I started using a subdomain on this domain for some project.

```
http://subdomain.mydomain.com
```

Those projects grew and now I have a structure like

```
http://subdomain.mydomain.com/project1
http://subdomain.mydomain.com/project2
http://subdomain.mydomain.com/project3/subproject1
http://subdomain.mydomain.com/project3/subproject2
http://subdomain.mydomain.com/project3/subproject3
http://subdomain.mydomain.com/project4
....
etc.
```

now I bought a new domain (shortdomain.com) where I plan not to move anything but everything should be accessible via redirects so everything looks like:

```
http://shortdomain.com
http://shortdomain.com/project1
http://shortdomain.com/project2
http://shortdomain.com/project3/subproject1
http://shortdomain.com/project3/subproject2
http://shortdomain.com/project3/subproject3
http://shortdomain.com/project4
...
etc.
```

So basically I need to do two things:
1. if anyone visits my old domain, redirect them the new naming structure. i.e. if someone loads `http://subdomain.mydomain.com/project2` they should be redirected to `http://shortdomain.com/project2`

1. when a user loads/redirected to `http://shortdomain.com/project2` this should actually load the content present at `http://subdomain.mydomain.com/project2`

So I will not manually migrate projects,codes and GBs of other data. I think this might be acievable by smart redirection only.

Just FYI:
1. I have full DNS control of both the domains
2. I am hosted on hostgator
3. I use cloudflare on the first domain and would like to continue using it

Answer (score 0):

> I think this might be acievable by smart redirection only.

No, redirection changes what's in the browser's location bar. If you redirect to `shortdomain.com` then the request will get sent to `shortdomain.com`, and have nothing to do with `subdomain.mydomain.com` anymore. If you redirect back to `subdomain.mydomain.com`, then the location bar in the browser will change as well.

What you really want to do is point `shortdomain.com` to the same server and document root that `subdomain.mydomain.com` is on. Then use this to redirect (either in htaccess file or server config):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://shortdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If, for whatever absurd reason you can't point the `shortdomain.com` DNS to the same webserver that serves `subdomain.mydomain.com`, or can't setup that webserver to accept requests for the `shortdomain.com` host, you need to setup a proxy server. And it'll work something like this:

2 Webservers, server A (hosts subdomain.domain.com) and server B (hosts shortdomain.com)

1. Someone requests `http://subdomain.mydomain.com/project3/subproject1`
2. server A gets the request and redirects the browser to `http://shortdomain.com/project3/subproject1`
3. browser's location bar changes to new location
4. server B gets the request and reverse proxies the request back to server A
5. server A gets the request *again* but must recognize that it is a proxy and then serve the page instead of redirecting

As you can see, this is a horrendously ineffecient solution. It's also a high possibility that your hosting service won't allow you to setup proxy servers.

Comment: It took hostgator some time to figure this out too. This works. but not completely as each of those projects may or may not have a .htaccess of their own. Which pretty much messed up everything. still looking for a stable solution.

Answer (score 0):

> `I have full DNS control of both the domains`

**With full control I assume you can enable `mod_proxy` as well on Apache web-server of `shortdomain.com`.** Once that is done set it all up this way.

On `subdomain.mydomain.com` enable `mod_rewrite` and place this rule in `Apache config` OR `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://shortdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

On `shortdomain.com` enable `mod_proxy`, `mod_rewrite` and place this rule in `Apache config` OR `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shortdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://subdomain.mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,P]
```